# Angular pattern validation with regex

Tags: regex, angular, typescript

I need to make a password pattern validator

the password should have:

- 1 uppercase letter
- 1 lowercase letter
- A number
- A minimum length of 8.

I found this regex pattern:

```
Validators.pattern('/^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d!$%@#£€*?&]')
```

however, the validator always claims my input is invalid

```
errors:    
   pattern:
      actualValue: "Test1234"
      requiredPattern: "^/^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*d)[A-Za-zd!$%@#£€*?&]$"
```

according to https://regex101.com/r/AfAdKp/1 this value is supposed to be valid.

**Edit:** to clarify, Test1234 is supposed to work

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have multiple issues with your current regex:

1. Your regex doesn't have a quantifier for character class
2. `Validators.pattern` doesn't need delimiters but you threw one at beginning
3. You should double escape tokens.

What you need is this:

```
Validators.pattern('^(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=\\D*\\d)[A-Za-z\\d!$%@#£€*?&]{8,}$');
```

See [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/6tKFnj/1)

Answer (score 3):

You have to add the quantifier `[A-Za-z\d!$%@#£€*?&]{8,}` to repeat the character class a minimum of 8 times and separate the assertions for an uppercase and lowercase character:

```
Validators.pattern('^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\\d)[A-Za-z\\d!$%@#£€*?&]{8,}$')
```

[`^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d!$%@#£€*?&]{8,}$`](https://regex101.com/r/RKCheN/1)

- `^` Assert position at the start of the string
- `(?=.*[A-Z])` Positive lookahead to assert that what follows is an uppercase character
- `(?=.*[a-z])` Positive lookahead to assert that what follows is an lowercase character
- `(?=.*\d)` Positive lookahead to assert that what follows is a digit
- `[A-Za-z\d!$%@#£€*?&]{8,}` Match any of the charachters in the character class 8 or more times
- `$` Assert position at the end of the line

```js
const strings = [
  "A88888jf",
  "Aa88888jf",
  "Aa888jf",
  "AAAAAAAAAAA",
  "aaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
  "2222222222222222",
  "1sAdfe44",
  "$#fd#######"
];
let pattern = /^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d!$%@#£€*?&]{8,}$/;

strings.forEach((s) => {
  console.log(s + " ==> " + pattern.test(s));
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work `pattern:{requiredPattern: "^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*d)[A-Za-zd!$%@#£€*?&]{8,}$", actualValue: "Test1234"}`

Comment: Why should `Test1234` not match?

Comment: That's the problem, it's supposed to match, but it gives me the error cause it doesn't.

Comment: @Nicolas Can you add the error to your question? Did you try it without the forward slash?